# How to put condition on next button in HTML/Js application?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating a HTML/JS application in which i need to put condition on next button so it can't move to next page i am using same button code for each section so if i want to put condition do i need to make separate button for each section ... i am not able to do it using `required` for radio button ..please suggest what should be done here

```js
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  // e.stopPropagation();
  $('ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.active').closest('li').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class="section-1-questions">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class="section-2-question">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
</div>
```

JS Part :-

```
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let fullName = document.querySelector('#fullName').value
  let email = document.querySelector('#email').value
  let age = document.querySelector('#age').value
  var ctx = document.querySelector('#resultsChart').getContext('2d');
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  var options = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Section 1", "Section 2"],
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Total Scored',
          data: [section1Question, section2Question, 30],
          backgroundColor: '#E91E63',
          borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
          label: 'Percentage %',
          data: [((section1Total / (section1Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2), ((section2Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2), 30],
          backgroundColor: '#004D40',
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        responsive: true,
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            reverse: false
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }

  //Final Results and validation
  if (fullName.value != '' && email.value != '' && age.value != '') {
    if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
      finalResults.innerHTML += genDetails(fullName, email, age)
      finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Results</h2>"
      finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
      finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
      finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Chart Results</h2>"
      document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("resultsChart").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
      new Chart(ctx, options); //show chart
    } else {
      finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
    }
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please enter your name, emial, age in the first section '
  }
}

function genDetails(name, email, age) {
  var result = "<h2>Personal Info</h2>"
  result += "<b>Full name:</b> <span>" + name + "</span><br>"
  result += "<b>Email name:</b> <span>" + email + "</span><br>"
  result += "<b>Age: </b> <span>" + age + "</span><br>"
  return result
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
  return result
}
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: There's not enough code in the example context to answer the question. Also note that it would make more sense to put the logic in the `click` event handler in a separate function and call that from both locations instead of creating a fake DOM event.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have added code can you help me resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was bored, and with a quick hand I made this decision for you. This solution consists in the default absence of a button further, and when selecting all the radios in the corresponding block, insert it as an element, using the `append()` method. Like this:

```
$(this).closest(".section_main").find(".btn-nav-group").append('<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>');
```

For correctness, create a **container** for your buttons. Like this:

```
<div class="btn-nav-group">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
</div>
```

The basis of this logic lies in checking the number of all radio buttons with the selected ones. Like this:

```
if (checked_radio.length == all_radio.length / 3) { ... }
```

Also, add the same class for the **main** div's. I added class `section_main`.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
    let all_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]');
    let checked_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]:checked');

    if (checked_radio.length == all_radio.length / 3) {
        $(this).closest(".section_main").find(".btn-nav-group").append('<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>');
    }
});

$(".btnNext").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.active").closest("li").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1" class="section_main tab-pane fade">
    <div class="section-1-questions">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                            1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                            2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                            3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                            1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                            2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                            3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                            1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                            2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                            3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-nav-group">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="section_main tab-pane fade">
    <div class="section-2-question">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                            1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                            2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                            3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                            1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                            2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                            3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                            1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                            2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                            3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                            1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                            2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                            3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-nav-group">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have used your solution but it didn't work .... here is the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66587704/append-method-is-not-working-for-putting-condition-on-button-for-html-js-appli ... please check @s.kuznetsov

Comment: @jugal, Hello. I made the code for you according to the code you provided, and in this snippet snippet the given code works well. After a while, you have edited your question. But I gave the solution before the edits you made to the question. You just need to adapt my solution to your generic code. And I believe I answered your question.

Comment: Yes i adapted but it haven't work you can check the code i have used in above given link ...thanks