# append() method is not working for putting condition on button for HTML/JS application

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a questionnaire application using HTML/JS.But i am stuck in one place i am using next button to go to next section of questions but i wanted to put condition to check if all the questions are answers or not for which i was using `append()` but it wasn't work for me i have used below code section:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
    let all_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]');
    let checked_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]:checked');

    if (checked_radio.length == all_radio.length / 3) {
        $(this).closest(".section_main").find(".btn-nav-group").append('<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>');
    }
});
```

I am trying to put condition on next button so if all the questions are not answered it will not move to next section and warning message will be displayed.Please someone help me with that.Detail code is given below:

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
    let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]');
    let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]');
    let sectionnew = document.querySelectorAll("#section1").values;
    let fullName = document.querySelector("#fullName").value;
    let email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
    let age = document.querySelector("#age").value;
    var ctx = document.querySelector("#resultsChart").getContext("2d");
    let section1Total = 0;
    let section2Total = 0;
    let section1Question = 0;
    let section2Question = 0;
    let finalResults = document.querySelector(".final-results");
    let result1 = "";
    let result2 = "";
    finalResults.innerHTML = "";

    //Section 1
    section1.forEach(function (radio, index) {
        if (radio.checked) {
            section2Question++;
            section1Total += +radio.value;
        }
    });
    console.log("radio value:", $("input[name='question1']:checked").val());
    // console.log( $("input[name=‘question1’]:checked").val());
    console.log("Ruchir");
    //Section 2
    section2.forEach(function (radio, index) {
        if (radio.checked) {
            section1Question++;
            section2Total += +radio.value;
        }
    });

    //Final Results and validation
    if (fullName.value != "" && email.value != "" && age.value != "") {
        if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
            finalResults.innerHTML += genDetails(fullName, email, age);
            finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Results</h2>";
            finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1);
            finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2);
            finalResults.innerHTML += $("input[name='question1']:checked").val();
            finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Chart Results</h2>";
            document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("resultsChart").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
        } else {
            finalResults.innerHTML = "Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section ";
        }
    } else {
        finalResults.innerHTML = "Snap! Please enter your name, emial, age in the first section ";
    }
}

function genDetails(name, email, age) {
    var result = "<h2>Personal Info</h2>";
    result += "<b>Full name:</b> <span>" + name + "</span><br>";
    result += "<b>Email name:</b> <span>" + email + "</span><br>";
    result += "<b>Age: </b> <span>" + age + "</span><br>";
    return result;
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
    var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>";
    var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>";
    result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>";
    return result;
}

$('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
    let all_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]');
    let checked_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]:checked');

    if (checked_radio.length == all_radio.length / 3) {
        $(this).closest(".section_main").find(".btn-nav-group").append('<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>');
    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnNext").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.active").closest("li").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
    });

    $(".btnPrevious").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.active").closest("li").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

```css
canvas {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    canvas {
        visibility: visible;
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
    .form-control {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .final-results * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .spider-chart * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .final-results,
    .form-control {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Survey</h2>
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#personalInfo" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active">Personal Info</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#results" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Results</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <div id="tabsContent" class="tab-content">
                <div id="personalInfo" class="tab-pane fade active show">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fullName">Full Name address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fullName" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter full name" />
                        <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your full name.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                        <small id="email" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your valid email address.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="age">Password</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" aria-describedby="age" placeholder="Age" />
                        <small id="age" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your age in number.</small>
                    </div>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div id="section1" class="section_main tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="section-1-questions">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-nav-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-nav-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious" >Previous</a> -->
                </div>
                <div id="section2" class="section_main tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="section-2-question">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-nav-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-nav-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious" >Previous</a> -->
                </div>
                <div id="results" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="final-results"></div>
                    <br />
                    <canvas id="resultsChart"></canvas>
                    <br />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
                        Show Results
                    </button>
                    <br />
                    <div class="spider-chart" id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="control" style="display: none;">
                        <a id="toemail" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to email</a>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What was the issue? Is the button not getting appended? Or is the click event not working for the button?

Comment: You have questions?

Comment: got it thanks @s.kuznetsov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html code you write this code, which should **not be** in this html by default:

```
<div class="btn-nav-group">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
</div>
```

In the previous question, I deliberately removed `<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>`, leaving only `<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>`. Like that:

```
<div class="btn-nav-group">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
</div>
```

Because the **Next** button will be added automatically, using the `append()` method:

```
$(this).closest(".section_main").find(".btn-nav-group").append('<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>');
```

This button is **Next** added to the same div with class `btn-nav-group`. Like that:

```
<div class="btn-nav-group">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
</div>
```

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
    let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]');
    let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]');
    let sectionnew = document.querySelectorAll("#section1").values;
    let fullName = document.querySelector("#fullName").value;
    let email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
    let age = document.querySelector("#age").value;
    var ctx = document.querySelector("#resultsChart").getContext("2d");
    let section1Total = 0;
    let section2Total = 0;
    let section1Question = 0;
    let section2Question = 0;
    let finalResults = document.querySelector(".final-results");
    let result1 = "";
    let result2 = "";
    finalResults.innerHTML = "";

    //Section 1
    section1.forEach(function (radio, index) {
        if (radio.checked) {
            section2Question++;
            section1Total += +radio.value;
        }
    });
    console.log("radio value:", $("input[name='question1']:checked").val());
    // console.log( $("input[name=‘question1’]:checked").val());
    console.log("Ruchir");
    //Section 2
    section2.forEach(function (radio, index) {
        if (radio.checked) {
            section1Question++;
            section2Total += +radio.value;
        }
    });

    //Final Results and validation
    if (fullName.value != "" && email.value != "" && age.value != "") {
        if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
            finalResults.innerHTML += genDetails(fullName, email, age);
            finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Results</h2>";
            finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1);
            finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2);
            finalResults.innerHTML += $("input[name='question1']:checked").val();
            finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Chart Results</h2>";
            document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("resultsChart").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
        } else {
            finalResults.innerHTML = "Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section ";
        }
    } else {
        finalResults.innerHTML = "Snap! Please enter your name, emial, age in the first section ";
    }
}

function genDetails(name, email, age) {
    var result = "<h2>Personal Info</h2>";
    result += "<b>Full name:</b> <span>" + name + "</span><br>";
    result += "<b>Email name:</b> <span>" + email + "</span><br>";
    result += "<b>Age: </b> <span>" + age + "</span><br>";
    return result;
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
    var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>";
    var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>";
    result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>";
    return result;
}

$('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
    let all_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]');
    let checked_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]:checked');

    if (checked_radio.length == all_radio.length / 3) {
        $(this).closest(".section_main").find(".btn-nav-group").append('<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>');
    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnNext").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.active").closest("li").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
    });

    $(".btnPrevious").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.active").closest("li").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

```css
canvas {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    canvas {
        visibility: visible;
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
    .form-control {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .final-results * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .spider-chart * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .final-results,
    .form-control {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Survey</h2>
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#personalInfo" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active">Personal Info</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#results" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Results</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <div id="tabsContent" class="tab-content">
                <div id="personalInfo" class="tab-pane fade active show">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fullName">Full Name address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fullName" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter full name" />
                        <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your full name.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                        <small id="email" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your valid email address.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="age">Password</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" aria-describedby="age" placeholder="Age" />
                        <small id="age" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your age in number.</small>
                    </div>
                    <!--a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a-->
                </div>
                <div id="section1" class="section_main tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="section-1-questions">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-nav-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious" >Previous</a> -->
                </div>
                <div id="section2" class="section_main tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="section-2-question">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-nav-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious" >Previous</a> -->
                </div>
                <div id="results" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="final-results"></div>
                    <br />
                    <canvas id="resultsChart"></canvas>
                    <br />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
                        Show Results
                    </button>
                    <br />
                    <div class="spider-chart" id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="control" style="display: none;">
                        <a id="toemail" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to email</a>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```